# how to write test case for create and update actions in rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Restaurant and Location models contains HABTM association. 
 how to write test cases for locations controller

```
def create
    @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
    @location =  @restaurant.locations.create(location_params)
    if @location.save   
        flash[:notice] = 'Location added!'   
        redirect_to admin_locations_path    
    else   
        flash[:error] = 'Failed to edit location!'   
        render :new   
    end   
end   

def update   
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])   
    if @location.update_attributes(location_params)   
        flash[:notice] = 'Location updated!'   
        redirect_to admin_locations_path   
    else   
        flash[:error] = 'Failed to edit Location!'   
        render :edit   
    end   
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code to create

```
restaurant = FactoryBot.create(:restaurant, name: Faker::Name.name)
post :create, params: { restaurant_id: restaurant.id, location: {restaurant_ids:[restaurant.id]}, format: 'js' }
expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
```

Try the following code to update

```
restaurant = FactoryBot.create(:restaurant, name: Faker::Name.name)
location = FactoryBot.create(:location, restaurant_id: restaurant.id)
patch :update, params: { id: location.id, location: {restaurant_ids:[restaurant.id]}, format: 'js' }
expect(response).to have_http_status(:success)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply create the spec using the following code snippet :

```
 Restaurant = FactoryBot.create(:Restaurant, name: Faker::Name.name)
 post :create, params: { location: {restaurant_ids:[Restaurant.id]}, format: 'json'
 expect(response.status).to eq(200)
```

Comment: it shows  Failure/Error: @restaurant = Restaurant.find(params[:restaurant_id])
     
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `find' for #<Restaurant:0x000055a0a0a29608>

Answer (score 0):

For simple controllers like this, I also like to ensure that the records are being created, so I would also test this:

```
restaurant = FactoryBot.create(:restaurant, name: Faker::Name.name)
expect {
  post(
    :create,
    params: {
      restaurant_id: restaurant.id,
      location: { restaurant_ids:[restaurant.id] },
      format: 'js'
    }
  )
}.to change{ Location.count }.by(1)
```